# Chrome extension Oauth2 authentication and verification issue

Tags: google-chrome-extension, oauth-2.0

I am developing chrome extension that uses several google API services. I've set up Oauth2 working code and authentication process works fine. However, I am getting "unverified app" screen  and would like to get rid of that. 
So, I went through google's verification process several times and I keep getting declined with explanation that I need to verify domain ownership of chromiumapp.org - which is I don't understand. Here's why:

By reading [google's documentation](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/identity#method-launchWebAuthFlow) about that topic I learned that I need to use https://.chromiumapp.org  endpoint for webAuthFlow redirect url, which I did and everything worked fine. But now google wants me to prove my ownership of chromiumapp.org, which is unclear to me...

Here's the process of setting chromiumapp domain url as redirect url:

- First I added https://my-extension-id.chromiumapp.org to Authorised redirect URIs section in google developers console.
- Then, google notified me that chromiumapp.org domain needs to be added to Authorised domains section first (under consent screen tab) in order to be able to add it toAuthorised redirect URIs section. So, I added chromiumapp.org to Authorised domains
- And now, when I apply for verification process, google wants me to verify my ownership of chromiumapp.org

Although I don't think that webAuthFlow code is relevant here, but here it is, just in case:

```
chrome.identity.launchWebAuthFlow(
    {
        "url": "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?" +
        $.param({
            "client_id": settings.CLIENT_ID,
            "scope": settings.SCOPE,
            "redirect_uri": getRedirectUri(),
            "response_type": "code",
            "access_type": "offline",
            "login_hint": "",
            "prompt": "consent select_account"
        }),
        "interactive": true
    },
    callback
);
```

My question is:

What am I doing wrong here?
Thanks!

Comment: Hi Josip, Did you ever find out about this? I've run into the same problem when trying to get a chrome extension oath screen verified: can't delete chromiumapp.org unless I delete credentials, but need that domain as the callback for oauth...

Comment: @jazzwhistle unfortunatelly no. In the end we decided to go with server-side authentication implementation instead.